# Select rows by column with condition Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Well I have a table(MYSQL) 'product', with one of the columns named 'category_id' that stores category id from another table 'category' . So there are multiple categories in 'category_id' column. eg table below. Now I want to select fixed number of product from each category(say 2), for eg i want to select 2 latest products from each category from the product table. What mysql query should i use, any idea?

**Product:**

```
+-------------+------+---------------------+
| category_id | name |      timestamp      |
+-------------+------+---------------------+
|           1 | abc  | 2016-02-27 16:04:00 |
|           1 | def  | 2016-02-28 16:10:00 |
|           1 | ghi  | 2016-02-29 16:11:00 |
|           2 | pqr  | 2016-02-27 16:04:00 |
|           2 | stu  | 2016-02-27 16:05:00 |
|           3 | vwx  | 2016-02-28 16:04:00 |
+-------------+------+---------------------+
```

Expected Result:

**Product:**

```
+-------------+------+---------------------+
| category_id | name |      timestamp      |
+-------------+------+---------------------+
|           1 | def  | 2016-02-28 16:10:00 |
|           1 | ghi  | 2016-02-29 16:11:00 |
|           2 | pqr  | 2016-02-27 16:04:00 |
|           2 | stu  | 2016-02-27 16:05:00 |
|           3 | vwx  | 2016-02-28 16:04:00 |
+-------------+------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Oh, any ones will work. Since I have many columns in my working table, i decided with above simplified tables that are sample tables not exact tables that i am working with, any suggestion can be helpful to me, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may help you...

Check the Output in SQL Fiddle Link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3942d2/6

```
SELECT
    category_id,
    name,
    tsDate
FROM
(
    SELECT
        category_id,
        name,
        tsDate,
        @rn := IF(@prev = category_id, @rn + 1, 1) AS rn,
        @prev := category_id
    FROM Product
    JOIN (SELECT @prev := NULL, @rn := 0) AS vars
    ORDER BY category_id, tsDate DESC, name
) AS T1
WHERE rn <= 2
```

Comment: Unknown column 'group' in 'field list' :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM my_table x
  JOIN my_table y
    ON y.category_id = x.category_id
   AND y.timestamp >= x.timestamp
 GROUP
    BY x.category_id,x.timestamp
HAVING COUNT(*) <= 2;
```